# How do I get data from an old (non-ruby) app to a new (ruby) app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-migration

I have an old CMS I built using Coldfusion. I would like to get the data from the old CMS to the new Ruby on Rails app. It's not a huge set, only about 1300 records. I need some advice/ideas.

The databases are on separate servers now but that can be fixed, and since I've followed the "Sensible Defaults" of RoR, the database structure is different.

Example of old data structure:

**Old CMS Table Example:**

```
CONTENT_ID  int
CONTENT_NAME    varchar 150
CONTENT_DESC    varchar 500
CONTENT_ACTIVE  tinyint
CONTENT_URL varchar 200
```

**New RoR CMS Table Example:**

```
id  int
name    varchar 255
visible tinyint 1
content text
created_at  datetime
updated_at  datetime
```

I'm a RoR newbie so I don't even know where to begin. I was going to use a program like [Navicat](http://navicat.com/) and just migrate the data from one server to another. Would that be okay? It has a [utility that will allow you to map columns](http://navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/win_manual/index.html).

Comment: Is it out of the question to simply point the new Rails app to the old database?

Comment: I don't know if you're new to Ruby as well as to Rails, but one thing that helped me understand a LOT was to write my own data parsing and data migration insertion scripts for a project I'm working on.  It will be a tough battle, but you'll learn tremendous amounts about the language and your problem domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using either CSV (comma-separated) or pipe-delimited plain text files to shuttle data dumps between different SQL engines has been the local favorite. CSV support is baked right into Ruby's standard lib.

Answer (score 2):

Navicat will work just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use whichever tool you're proficient with. I would probably either

- dump the tables to SQL file, then run couple of regexp search-replacements on it, and import SQL to another database or
- hack a small [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) based script to pump the records from one database to another.

But I guess there are lots of specialized tools for data migration out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

old_app_db -> csv/json/xml -> new_app_db

I believe that writing a script (Ror migration ?) for the import purpose is the best, it will save you lots of time in the future ;)